# Select emulator using Selendroid

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, selendroid

I am trying to select emulator when running Selendroid and found this flag

-emulatorPort
"Specify the port number to start running emulators on."

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5558   device
```

Since I have two emulators running I would like to choose one or the other when running my tests. I therefore use the flag when starting up selendroid

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.11.0-with-dependencies.jar -app app.apk -emulatorPort 5554
```

The test code that I've written starts with this

```
SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities("app.package.name:1.0);
capa.setCapability(SelendroidCapabilities.EMULATOR, true);

driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);
```

But now it crashes when I run my test

```
INFO: executing command: /Applications/Android/platform-tools/adb shell pm clear app.package.name
io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /Applications/Android/platform-tools/adb shell pm clear app.package.name
    at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.AbstractDevice.executeCommand(AbstractDevice.java:176)
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.AbstractDevice.executeCommand(AbstractDevice.java:171)
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.AbstractDevice.clearUserData(AbstractDevice.java:199)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.release(DeviceStore.java:81)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.createNewTestSession(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:245)
    at io.selendroid.server.handler.CreateSessionHandler.handle(CreateSessionHandler.java:42)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidServlet.handleRequest(SelendroidServlet.java:143)
    at io.selendroid.server.BaseServlet.handleHttpRequest(BaseServlet.java:67)
    at io.selendroid.server.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: error: more than one device and emulator
error: more than one device and emulator
```

Seems like id does not select the correct emulator using "-s emulator-5554", is this a bug or have I completely misunderstood the flag "-emulatorPort". If I close one of the emulators everything works fine.

Or do I have to use [Selendroid Grid](http://selendroid.io/scale.html), just seems like such an overkill for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

As the description of the emulatorPort flag says it used to specify the port of a newly spawned emulator, not to choose from already running emulators. To choose from already running emulators use something like

```
capa.setSerial("emulator-5554");
```

replacing 5554 with the port number of the desired emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your script:

```
DesiredCapabilities capa=DesiredCapabilities.android();
capa.setCapability(SelendroidCapabilities.EMULATOR, true);
capa.setCapability(SelendroidCapabilities.ANDROID_TARGET, DeviceTargetPlatform.ANDROID18);
SelendroidDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);
```